# InvalidCastException when retrieving data from SqlDataReader

Tags: sql, vb.net, runtime

How can I get rid of:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "Type" to type
>   'Integer' is not valid.'"

On the line:

```vb
Dim usertype = Reader.GetString("Type")
```

This is my full code:

```vb
Private Sub OKbt1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OKbt1.Click
    Call Connect() ' [ connection to module ]'
    Dim Reader As SqlDataReader

    Try
        Dim command As New SqlCommand("select * from uinfo where password = '" & PASStb2.Text & "'", sqlConn)
        Reader = command.ExecuteReader
        Reader.Read()

        Dim count As Integer = 0

        While Reader.Read
            count = count + 1
        End While

        If count = 1 Then

            ' ** MY ERROR **
            Dim usertype = Reader.GetString("Type")

            If usertype = "admin" Then
                'MsgBox("username and password are correct")
                MAIN_MENU.Show()

                For a = 0 To 500

                Next
                Me.Hide()
                sqlConn.Close()
                sqlConn.Dispose()

            ElseIf usertype = "user" Then

                For a = 0 To 500

                Next
                Me.Hide()
                'MsgBox("username and password are correct")
                USERMENU.Show()

            End If

        ElseIf count > 1 Then
            MsgBox("username and password are duplicate")

        Else
            MsgBox("username and password are not correct")
        End If

        sqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    Finally
        sqlConn.Dispose()

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Declare usertype  as  Dim usertype as String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SqlDataReader.GetString Method (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx)  needs an integer (column index) as a parameter. So you need

```
Dim usertype as String = Cstr(Reader("Type"))
```

or

```
Dim usertype = Reader.GetString(Reader.GetOrdinal("Type"))
```

or

```
Dim usertype = Reader.GetFieldValue(Of String)("Type")
```

Be aware that non of those posibilites can handle DBnull.

Comment: thanks mate :) big help didn't notice my using INT32 so i checked it , now is working thanks mate .. hoooray

Answer (score 0):

'Reader.GetString' accepts an integer parameter, not a string.  Or, do

```
Reader.Item("Type").ToString()
```

Comment: i try it but this error is popping 
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.'

Answer (score 0):

Declare usertype as Dim usertype as String and then assign value to it like usertype = Reader.Item("Type").ToString().
also you need to check value return by Reader.GetString("Type") it might be null.  Turn "**Option Strict" On** It will help in the long run.

Comment: i try it but this error is popping System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Comment: @Hardik check why it is null. check with column name is same as in database or that column contain any data or not

Answer (score 0):

```
 **Dim usertype = Reader.GetString("Type") // MY ERROR**
```

You are passing a value of string which obviously is wrong

GetString function accepts integer.
You might want to instantiate a data which is integer and pass it through getstring.

```
Dim usertype = Reader.GetString(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you may not getting data from "Reader" object properly

Try this instead :

```vb
Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT  * FROM uinfo WHERE  password = '" & PASStb2.Text & "'", connection)
    connection.Open()
    Dim READER As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    If READER.HasRows Then
        While READER.Read()
            Console.WriteLine("{0}" & vbTab & "{1}", READER.GetInt32(0), READER.GetString(1))
        End While
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("No rows found.")
    End If

    READER.Close()
```

Comment: I think the OP is using vb.net not C#

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters. I let the server do the counting. Saves you some lines of code.

```vb
Private Sub OKbt1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OKbt1.Click
        Call Connect() ' [ connection to module ]'
        Dim Reader As SqlDataReader
        Try
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select usertype, Count(*) from uinfo Group By usertype where [password] = @password;", sqlConn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PASStb2.Text
                Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If Reader.HasRows Then
                    Reader.Read()
                    Dim usertype As String = Reader.GetString(0)
                    Dim count As Integer = Reader.GetInt32(1)
                    If count = 1 Then
                        If usertype = "admin" Then
                            MAIN_MENU.Show()
                            Hide()
                        ElseIf usertype = "user" Then
                            USERMENU.Show()
                            Hide()
                        End If
                    ElseIf count > 1 Then
                        MsgBox("username and password are duplicate")
                    End If
                Else
                    MsgBox("username and password are not correct")
                End If
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            sqlConn.Close()
            sqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```